# Why my Logistic Regression Score is always 1.0?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using sklearn in python and the idea of the implementation is to predict SPX 500 by using the Logistic Regression.

I got the SPX historical prices from yfinance and calculated 5 features (x) based on daily returns (which I calculated as well).

The dependent variable (y) is 1 for positive retunrs and 0 for negative returns.

When I predicted the model and check the model.score(), the value is always 1.  But Why?

the code is:

```
# Import the data
df= yf.download('^GSPC', start="2018-1-1", end="2020-10-20")
df = df.dropna()

df['Return'] = np.log(df['Adj Close']/df['Adj Close'].shift(1))

# Create Indicators
df['Ret_1'] = df['Return'].shift(1)
df['Ret_2'] = df['Return'].shift(2)
df['Adj Close-Adj Close 1day'] = df['Adj Close'] - df['Adj Close'].shift(1)
df['Adj Close-Adj Close 5days'] = df['Adj Close'] - df['Adj Close'].shift(5)
df['S_10'] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=5).mean()

df = df.dropna()
X = df.iloc[:,-5:]

y =np.where(df['Return'] > 0 ,1,0)


# Split the Dataset and Instantiate Logistic Regression
split = int(0.7*len(df))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:split], X[split:], y[:split], y[split:]

model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit (X_train,y_train)
predicted = model.predict(X_test)

print(model.score(X_test,y_test))
```

Comment: @Progman python

Comment: Python (spyder)

Comment: Welcome to SO; for the next time 1) please use the appropriate tags 2) format code comments properly (not by `" "`).

Comment: Thx @desertnaut . Coud you give example of appropriate tags?

Comment: See the already edited tags; `scikit-learn` is *much* more informative than, say the ultra-vague & general `supervised-learning`.

Answer (score 2):

Among the 5 features that you are inputing in your logistic regression, the variable

```
df['Adj Close-Adj Close 1day'] = df['Adj Close'] - df['Adj Close'].shift(1)
```

has the same sign as the underlying variable `df['Return']` that you are using in the target

```
y =np.where(df['Return'] > 0 ,1,0)
```

hence the Logistic regression is going to match very well.

Moreover both use `df['Adj Close']`, so you are trying to predict a target value using something that in fact enables you to precisely calculate the target value.

Comment: Got it.
In this case, for the model to be more "real"  I should use different features that are not related directly to the dependent variable.  Am I right?

Comment: You are in fact trying to find features related to your target, by definition of prediction.
But these should not enable you to calculate the target exactly... otherwise it's no more a prediction.

Comment: What should I do to use Lasso in this code instead of LogisticRegression? @Bluexm